# There is no sound in the video I created

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -i video.mp4 -i watermark.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=854x480[intro];[1:v][2:v] overlay=x=10:y=10,drawtext=text=TEXT':box=1:boxborderw=5:boxcolor=black:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-th:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:enable='between(t,0,15)'[main];[intro][main]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[out]" -map "[out]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy out.mp4
```

I want the video to work properly with the sound problem fixed.
I'm waiting for your help

Comment: Do intro and video both have audio?

Comment: there is sound only in the video, there is no sound in the intro. When I combine these two videos, the sound disappears.